# how to replicate docker volume host machine to another host machine volume--volume high availability host to host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-machine, docker-volume

I tried Gluster service in host(cluster machine 1 and machine 2) volume but not supported docker PostgreSQL container data

i want to replicate docker volume machine 1 to machine 2 for fail-over purpose(docker host to host volume high availability) and i want run another PostgreSQL container in machine 2 with replica of machine in parallel vice-versa